# NextJs router 404ing on refresh from Digital Ocean

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, digital-ocean

I have a NextJs project exported as a static site being hosted on Digital Ocean's App platform, using next/router to handle routing.

The issue is that refreshing on any route outside of the base route "/" throws back a 404. Other answers mention using the `error_document` or `catchall_document` in DO's app specification as a fallback file, but the other routes still 404 on refresh and redirect back to that fallback document.

What is the proper way to tell the platform to route to the correct url on refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and what solved it was going to my App settings, and on App Spec updating the .yaml file with all my routes.

Where it says

```
routes:
```

- path: /

Update it with your other routes like:

```
routes:
```

- path: /
- path: /Menu

Answer (score 3):

##### Solve the App reloading leads to 404 site

- Download current app spec from https://cloud.digitalocean.com/apps, in the settings tab you will find App Spec to `yourappname.yaml` file
- Add `catchall_document: index.html`

Source: [APP Platform: App reloading leads to 404 site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/app-platform-app-reloading-leads-to-404-site)

Comment: This one worked in 2023, the accepted answer downside is if you have a large webapp you need to specify each path on your Yaml, but adding catchall_document will solve that problem.