# NextJs 404ing on deployment but not dev

Tags: reactjs, next.js, digital-ocean, vercel

Very similar to this question:
[NextJs router 404ing on refresh from Digital Ocean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66511700/nextjs-router-404ing-on-refresh-from-digital-ocean)

I also have a NextJs project that I want to export as a static site to host on Digital Ocean / Vercel. Everything works perfectly when running `yarn dev` locally, but deploying causes loads of 404 errors: any refreshing (except for the base route) throws a 404 and images also can't be loaded.

Adding `catchall_document: index.html` removes 404 errors but just redirects all refreshes to the base route. Additionally, adding any sort of `routes:` to my app spec does not compile. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to share your code so that we can debug and find the issue

Comment: I'm kind of at a loss as for what code to show, since I have absolutely no idea where this error comes from / how to localize the error. If you want to see specific files, I'll edit the post with the code provided

Comment: Do you have a github repo for this?